# Solr - Constrain More Like This Results Only

Tags: solr, lucene

Let's say I have a particular sweater with `code:blue-sweater` that is `color:blue`. I would like to find similar products using the `description` field, with the constraint that similar products are not blue (`-color:blue`).

From the [Solr wiki](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/MoreLikeThis):

> If you want to filter the similar results given by MoreLikeThis you
>   have to use the MoreLikeThisHandler. It will consider the similar
>   document result set as the main one so will apply the specified
>   filters (fq) on it. If you use the MoreLikeThisComponent and apply
>   query filters it will be applyed to the result set returned by the
>   main query (QueryComponent) and not to the one returned by the
>   MoreLikeThisComponent.

These are the params I'm using; the `qt` param sets the request handler as `MoreLikeThis`:

```
    {
      q: "code:"blue-sweater"",
      qt: "mlt",
      mlt: "true",
      fl: "description,brand,gender,price",
      mlt.boost: "true",
      mlt.fl: "description",
      fq: "-color:"blue"",
      rows: "6",
      mlt.mintf: "0",
      mlt.mindf: "0"
    }
```

The issue is that I can only specify the `FilterQuery` param once, which sets `fq` for both the initial query ("code:"blue-sweater") and for the MoreLikeThis results).

Since the filter of `-color:blue` excludes my initial query (the blue sweater), I am left with no MoreLikeThis results. How do I get around this?

If the only products in the core are `color:blue`, I still want to return them, but they should be at the bottom of possible results.

**Edit**

I did some digging around, and it seems that the only way to boost a MoreLikeThis query is by with `mlt.qf`:

> Query fields and their boosts using the same format as that used by
>   the DisMax Query Parser. These fields must also be specified in
>   mlt.fl. ([source](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/7_5/morelikethis.html#common-parameters-for-morelikethis))

I have tried to do a regular query with the DisMax parser with a value constraint (like `in_stock:[* TO 10]`), but the constraint on the field value gets ignored entirely. You can only do plain boosts on a field (`color^2`).

So it seems that this is a limitation of MoreLikeThis relying on the DisMax parser instead of the `EdisMax` parser.

Comment: Instead of negating you could try to [boost the term](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/7_4/the-standard-query-parser.html) with a fraction of one, e.g. `color:blue^0.1`. This would degrade the relevance of color:blue matches drastically.

Comment: For some reason, even a boost of ^0.00001 isn't making a dent. I'm providing a regular `boost` param.